# What is the shrink() method in jasmine-check?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, immutable.js

While studying the ImmutableJS test file `Range.ts` I come across the `jasmine-check` utility.

**Question**: what does the `shrink` method do and how do I find out more about the `jasmine-check` API?

Exmaple:

```
import * as jasmineCheck from 'jasmine-check';
jasmineCheck.install();

import { Range} from 'immutable';

describe('Range', () => {

  // ...

  var shrinkInt = gen.shrink(gen.int);

  check.it('slices the same as array slices',
    [shrinkInt, shrinkInt, shrinkInt, shrinkInt],
    function (from, to, begin, end) {
      var r = Range(from, to);
      var a = r.toArray();
      expect(r.slice(begin, end).toArray()).toEqual(a.slice(begin, end));
    }
  );

  // ...

});
```

Comment: Check out the documentation for `testcheck-js` - https://github.com/leebyron/testcheck-js